# How difficult would it be to use metadata from web services to build drop down menu in J D Edwards

Tags: metadata, erp, jde, jdedwards

Looking for a way to harmonise data between a number of copies of J D Edwards.
Currently users type in data that should be in drop downs to prevent errors.
How feasible is it to create a web service with all the controlled lists and then use these services to build the drop downs and ensure the data is correct in all copies of the system?
I have no experience of J D Edwards

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific feature in JDE for this - [User Defined Codes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17984_01/doc.898/e14721/user_defined_codes.htm). UDC's are the lists of correct values for a specific field/data item.